# glBindFramebufferOES - documentation?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, framebuffer

I am trying to find the reference pages / documentation of the method `glBindFramebufferOES`(and related directives) and spent a good amount of time googling. I am a registered iPhone developer and searching the resources provided by Apple in the Dev Centre turned up nothing.

Please, can someone point me to where I can read the specification of `glBindFramebufferOES`? A link would be great but if it's not publicly available a short explanation how I can find it in the dev centre would be equally appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OES suffix is present only with OpenGL ES 1.1. In OpenGL ES 2.0, it's simply `glBindFramebuffer()` and you can find [the documentation for this](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBindFramebuffer.xml) at [the Khronos Group](http://www.khronos.org). [Their hosted specifications](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/) are the primary reference for OpenGL ES functions and extensions.

Answer (score 0):

It's defined by the [OES_framebuffer_object](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_framebuffer_object.txt) extension.